# Mapply with data.frame/list as the Arguments for the Function

Tags: r

In short, I have a larger function that creates data.frames that are subsets of a larger data.frame and are named after the arguments of the function. It's building data.frames for raw data AND the outputs and the predictive output of Holt-Winters...meaning it is creating multiple data.frames. A small example is the following (though there's not enough intervals here to actually generate a ts class data.frame):

```
Group <- c("Primary_Group","Primary_Group","Primary_Group","Primary_Group","Primary_Group","Primary_Group","Secondary_Group","Secondary_Group","Secondary_Group","Secondary_Group","Secondary_Group","Secondary_Group","Tertiary_Group","Tertiary_Group","Tertiary_Group","Tertiary_Group","Tertiary_Group","Tertiary_Group")
Day <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
Type <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B","A","A","A","B","B","B","A","A","A","B","B","B")
Value <- c(7,3,10,3,9,4,0,9,3,10,1,6,3,4,10,2,3,1)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Group,Day,Type,Value))

Fun <- function(Group,Type, A, B, G){
    df <- Data[Data$Group== Group & Data$Type== Type, ]
    assign(paste(Group,Type,"_df",sep = ''), df, envir = parent.frame()) 
    df_holtwinters <- HoltWinters(ts(Data[Data$Group== Group & Data$Type== Type, ], 
                                  frequency = 365), alpha = A, beta = B, gamma = G)
    assign(paste(Group,Type,"_hw",sep = ''), df_holtwinters, envir = parent.frame()) 
}
```

You'll notice that the *Group* and *Type* are characters, while *A, B, G* are either numeric or `NULL`.

If I now have a data.frame composed of lists values, how could I best loop the above function (likely with `mapply`) to use the values from each column in row one...then each column from row 2 etc - creating several data frames.

```
argGroup <- c("Primary_Group","Primary_Group","Secondary_Group","Secondary_Group","Tertiary_Group","Tertiary_Group")
argType <- c("A","B","A","B","A","B")
argA <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
argB <- c(0.05, 0.05, NA, NA, NA, NULL)
argG <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)

argGroup[is.na(argGroup)] <- list(NULL)
argType[is.na(argType)] <- list(NULL)
argA[is.na(argA)] <- list(NULL)
argB[is.na(argB)] <- list(NULL)
argG[is.na(argG)] <- list(NULL)

Arguments <- cbind(argType, argType, argA, argB, argG)
```

Ideally, I would get the following data.frames to generate...

```
Primary_Group_A_df
Primary_Group_A_hw
Primary_Group_B_df
Primary_Group_B_hw
Secondary_Group_A_df
Secondary_Group_A_hw
Secondary_Group_B_df
Secondary_Group_B_hw
Tertiary_Group_A_df
Tertiary_Group_A_hw
Tertiary_Group_B_df
Tertiary_Group_B_hw
```

It would also be helpful to understand how to best (most automated way) `rbind` all the *_df* together and all the *_hw* together.

Any help would be amazing and very appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: Parfait, the reason for setting the list NULL is so that I can have a data.frame with lists that contain both numeric values (say 0.05) but then also have NULL (not NA) as a value. In short, Holt-Winters' gives you the option to either write alpha = 0.05 (numeric value) or alpha = NULL, where the alpha is just optimized.


I can reduce this thread to one simpler question: How do I apply a multiple column data.frame to a function using mapply, so that it loops through each row for the arguments (meaning each column in row 1 are the arguments for iteration one...then row two...etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid flooding your global environment with many similarly structured objects. Consider using a container such as a list to hold the many dataframes. One useful method is `by` to subset your dataframe by one or more factor(s) such as *Group* and *Type* to return a list of dataframes. Also, don't iterate by rows but `merge` arguments with data for one pass of arguments per subset.

Specifically, call `by` twice for *df* and *hw* lists. But first, merge the *df* and *Arguments* data frames by *Group* and *Type*. One challenge is `NULL` cannot be stored in a data frame, so consider saving `"NULL"` string and assign temp variables to pass into the `HW` arguments. Unfortunately, this will cast entire column as character type which you will need to convert with `as.numeric` for non-NULL values.

**Merge**

```
Group <- c("Primary_Group","Primary_Group","Secondary_Group","Secondary_Group",
           "Tertiary_Group","Tertiary_Group")
Type <- c("A","B","A","B","A","B")
argA <- c("NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL")
argB <- c(0.05, 0.05, "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL")
argG <- c("NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL")

Arguments <- data.frame(Group, Type, argA, argB, argG, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df <- merge(df, Arguments, by=c("Group", "Type"))
```

**Dataframe List** *(with named df elements)*

```
# ORDER FOR NAMING LATER
df <- with(df, df[order(Type, Group),])

# DATAFRAME LIST
df_list <- by(df, df[c("Group", "Type")], identity)
# RENAME LIST
df_list <- setNames(df_list, unique(paste0(df$Group, "_", df$Type, "_df")))

# REFERENCE ELEMENTS
df_list$Primary_Group_A_df
df_list$Secondary_Group_A_df
df_list$Tertiary_Group_A_df
...
```

**HW List** *(with named hw elements)*

```
# HW LIST
hw_list <- by(df, df[c("Group", "Type")], function(sub) {
  # CONDITIONALLY ASSIGN TEMP VARIABLES 
  # (BEING SUBSETS: max(arg*)==min(arg*)==mean(arg*)==median(arg*))
  if(!is.na(max(sub$argA)) & max(sub$argA) == "NULL") { tmpA <- NULL } 
  else { tmpA <- max(as.numeric(sub$argA)) }

  if(!is.na(max(sub$argB)) & max(sub$argB) == "NULL") { tmpB <- NULL } 
  else { tmpB <- max(as.numeric(sub$argB)) }

  if(!is.na(max(sub$argG)) & max(sub$argG) == "NULL") { tmpG <- NULL } 
  else { tmpG <- max(as.numeric(sub$argG)) }

  # PASS ARGS ONCE PER SUBSET 
  return(HoltWinters(ts(sub, frequency = 365), alpha=tmpA, beta=tmpB, gamma=tmpG))
})

# RENAME LIST
hw_list <- setNames(hw_list, unique(paste0(df$Group, "_", df$Type, "_hw")))

# REFERENCE ELEMENTS
hw_list$Primary_Group_A_hw
hw_list$Secondary_Group_A_hw
hw_list$Tertiary_Group_A_hw
...
```

**Output** *(using 3 for HW's frequency to align with posted data)*

```
> hw_list$Primary_Group_A_hw
Holt-Winters exponential smoothing with trend and additive seasonal component.

Call:
HoltWinters(x = ts(sub[c("Group", "Day", "Type", "Value")], frequency = 3),     alpha = tmpA, beta = tmpB, gamma = tmpG)

Smoothing parameters:
 alpha: 0.2169231
 beta : 0.05
 gamma: 0.1

Coefficients:
          [,1]
a   2.89129621
b   0.08783715
s1  0.54815382
s2 -0.12485260
s3  0.21087038

> hw_list$Secondary_Group_A_hw
Holt-Winters exponential smoothing with trend and additive seasonal component.

Call:
HoltWinters(x = ts(sub[c("Group", "Day", "Type", "Value")], frequency = 3),     alpha = tmpA, beta = tmpB, gamma = tmpG)

Smoothing parameters:
 alpha: 0.752124
 beta : 0
 gamma: 0

Coefficients:
            [,1]
a   3.691664e+00
b   3.333333e-01
s1  3.333333e-01
s2 -1.480388e-16
s3 -3.333333e-01

> hw_list$Tertiary_Group_A_hw
Holt-Winters exponential smoothing with trend and additive seasonal component.

Call:
HoltWinters(x = ts(sub[c("Group", "Day", "Type", "Value")], frequency = 3),     alpha = tmpA, beta = tmpB, gamma = tmpG)

Smoothing parameters:
 alpha: 0.3145406
 beta : 0
 gamma: 0

Coefficients:
            [,1]
a   3.022946e+00
b  -3.333333e-01
s1 -3.333333e-01
s2 -1.480388e-16
s3  3.333333e-01
```

Comment: Excellent. Very helpful and very great advice.

Answer (score 0):

You're losing type information by using `as.data.frame(cbind(...))`,
just use `data.frame` directly:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  Group = rep(c("Primary_Group", "Secondary_Group", "Tertiary_Group"), each = 6L),
  Day = rep(1L:3L, 6L),
  Type = rep(rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3L), 3L),
  Value = c(7,3,10,3,9,4,0,9,3,10,1,6,3,4,10,2,3,1)
)
```

Afterwards, I presume you can do the following:

```
split_data <- split(Data, as.list(Data[, c("Group", "Type")]))
dfs <- do.call(rbind, split_data)

dfs_hw <- lapply(split_data, function(sub_data) {
  Map(argA, argB, argG, f = function(A, B, G) {
    HoltWinters(ts(sub_data, frequency = 365), alpha = A, beta = B, gamma = G)
  })
})

dfs_hw <- do.call(rbind, unlist(dfs_hw, recursive = FALSE))
```

But I get an error from `HoltWinters`,
so I can't say for sure.
Also, I think `dfs` simply has `Data` again, just reordered.

Comment: Still amazing how many useRs overlook `by` which replaces `split` + `lapply`!

Comment: Fancy. I don't now why I had never seen it before.